# How to show a table on click of a button in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to list files from mysql table to a webpage in php. For this i use tables so that i have more regular view. Now there are n numbers of tables on a page. This n is depending upon a mysql query. I am able to list the files on the page. But if numbers of rows in table get increased and value of n is also get increased then my page length will be very long. So i want to give a tree view to each table. Like there will be a button over each table with value '+'. when i click on it the value get change to '-' and that table should be visible. 
Here what i tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".show").html("<input type='checkbox'>");
  $('.tree td').hide();
  $('th ').click( function() {
    $(this).parents('table').find('td').toggle(); 
  });
});

 <table width="100%" class="tree">
 <tr width="20px"><th colspan="2" class="show"> </th></tr>                          
 <tr>
   <td width="50%"><b>Name</b></td>
   <td width="50%"><b>Last Updated</b></td>
 </tr>

  while($row = $result_sql->fetch_assoc()) 
  {
         <tr>
         <td width='50%'><a href='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=464&name_file={$row['name']}&cat={$cat}&sec={$sec}' target='_blank'>{$row['title']}</a></td>
         <td width='50%'>{$row['created']}</td>                             
         </tr>
  }
  </table>
```

**This is not exact code.**

as you can see i am able to do it but i am using a chackbox. i want to have a button with value + or - . There is one problem with this code. The line in which checkbox is showing if i click on it the table is expanded means it taking the entire row not only the checkbox. So anybody can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: if u have multiple tables which increases your page length then u can use "accordion"..may be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/Lbutf/

Comment: Thanks ashish but this is not my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is a code sample, in the future try to provide a jsFiddle to make it easier for people to help.  If you want to use `+/-`, you can make a minor modification like [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/xhLUK/1/)

```
<th colspan="2" width="100%"><span class="show"></span></th>
```

I basically added the **show** class to a span within the `<th>` and attached a click handler on it as well.  When you click on it, it will toggle the `<td>` within the **parent** `<table>`... in addition, it will check the text-value in the `<th>` and inverse it

```
$('.show').click(function () {
    $(this).parents('table').find('td').toggle();
    $(this).text() == '+' ? $(this).text('-') : $(this).text('+');
});
```

Since you don't need a **checkbox** and you are using a `<span>`, it won't wrap across the entire `<th>`.  Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: even though i found the answer by myself C.S.'s effort deserves to check the solution. And the solution is correct exactly what i wanted. Only in meantime i am able to solve it also. But i am accepting and up voting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Get solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".show").html("<input type='button' value='+' class='treebtn'>");
$('.tree td').hide();
$('.treebtn ').click( function() {
$(this).parents('table').find('th').parents('table').find('td').toggle(); 
if (this.value=="+") this.value = "-";
else this.value = "+";

});
});
```

It is working fine the way i wanted.